# absolute div position with overflow-y:scroll

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div's 
at the first div I need to display an absolute inner dive which will be displayed above the rest of the dives

here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/b3PXF/

all is working ok but at the moment that I add  an

> overflow-y:scroll;

to the parent div the absolute div is displayed beneath the second div instead of above it

here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/sV8cs/

is there is something that can be done to solve this? so even if the parent div has an overflow-y:scroll I can still see it above it?

here is my code

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.panel{
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.icon_but{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.comment_wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.comment_body{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:999;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid  #c5c5c5;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel left">
  <div class="comment_wrapper">
    <div class="icon_but">click me</div>
    <div class="comment_body">hi I am the comment</div>
  </div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="panel left"> div2 </div>
<div class="panel left"> div3 </div>
```

Comment: There is no change at all! What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: The div is absolutely positioned. It means it will be positioned relative to its nearest relatively positioned parent. And hence when you explicitly apply an `overflow`, it gets contained within the parent. You could use a container/wrapper and then position against that.

Comment: the change between the states is that in the first one the absolute div is above the second panel http://jsfiddle.net/b3PXF/
but when I add to the parent panel the overflow-y css property it displayes beneath it http://jsfiddle.net/sV8cs/

Comment: Please read my second comment. You need a wrapper div.

Comment: ok now I understood the root of the problem, thanks it helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an wrapper for the "text" you want displayed with `overflow-y:scroll;`

Checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/sV8cs/1/

I have added the div `<div class="comments">`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel left">

    <div class="comment_wrapper">
        <div class="icon_but">click me</div>
        <div class="comment_body">hi I am the comment</div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel left">
div2
</div>
<div class="panel left">
div3
</div>

.comment-text{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```